# how to receive mails in application using action mailer.But with my own function , instead of def receive(mail) end

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Once a method called receive is defined in any mailer, Action Mailer will parse the raw incoming email into an email object, decode it, instantiate a new mailer, and pass the email object to the mailer receive instance method. Here's an example:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def receive(email)
    page = Page.find_by_address(email.to.first)
    page.emails.create(
      subject: email.subject,
      body: email.body
    )

    if email.has_attachments?
      email.attachments.each do |attachment|
        page.attachments.create({
          file: attachment,
          description: email.subject
        })
      end
    end
  end
end
```

My doubt is instead of this function

```
def receive(email)
  ......
end
```

how i can receive mail in my own function example :

```
def reveiver_mailer
  .......
end
```

Comment: Where you want to define reveiver_mailer function?

Comment: i want to define in controller

Comment: You need to inherit ActionMailer::Base to use mailing methods..

Comment: what about function name it should be receive or it can some other?